Discrepancy in Code Coverage Reporting Between GHC 8.10.7 and GHC 9.4.7
I've encountered a discrepancy in code coverage reporting when using different versions of GHC. Specifically, I'm seeing differences in how coverage is reported for derived Show instances in my Haskell project. Here's an overview of the issue:
Code Example:
data Test = Hello | World deriving Show

test :: Bool
test = (show Hello /= "") && (show World /= "")

Problem:
When using GHC 8.10.7, the Show instance for the Test data type is marked as fully covered.
When using GHC 9.4.7, the same code marks the Show instance as partially covered (highlighted in yellow in the coverage report).
Steps to Reproduce:
Compile the code with -fhpc using GHC 8.10.7 and GHC 9.4.7.
Run the tests and generate the coverage report.
Coverage Command:
stack build --test --coverage
stack test --coverage
hpc markup your-project.tix --destdir=coverage

Observations:
The issue seems specific to the derived Show instances.
There are no differences in the test results; only the coverage reporting is affected.
Question:
What changes between GHC 8.10.7 and GHC 9.4.7 could be causing this difference in code coverage reporting?
Are there any known workarounds or configurations that can help ensure consistent coverage reporting across these GHC versions?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Yes, I've seen the same issue, it appears that the "code" the deriving (Show) generates, does not "backlink" to deriving (Show).

Take this straight to the GHC bug tracker.

@DanielWagner, are you doing it? Or are you suggesting I should? Where is it?

You should. It's here.

I am not sure why, but my request to signup for the bug tracker is rejected.
